# Retrofit associative array

Tags: retrofit2

I want to post associative array with retrofit on android but I can't figure it out yet.Below is the expected request to server using post

{
                "que_id": "4",
                "que_assistants": [
                    14
                ],
                "opening_cash_lines": [
                    {
                        "denomination": "1000",
                        "count": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "denomination": "500",
                        "count": "2"
                    }
                ]
            }

Someone help me out on this

Comment: Question is not clear enough what you want? you want to parse this data? consume this data in some other way?

Comment: Thanks , I sorted it by posting as an object with the @Body attribute